# Pendulum: Deduce proportionality from experiment

Tags: classical-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, data-analysis

*I know, very easy for all of you, but I'm a beginner in physics ... ;)*

I have to work with the mathematical pendulum. After some experiments (changing mass, chaning pendulum's length etc.), I could see that the changes in mass have no effects on the cycle duration ($T$) but changing the length of the pendulum ($\ell$) has. So I have to find out how exactly they correlate, right?

What I thought about: We know (from Huygen's law) that the formula is:

$$T = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{\ell}{g}}$$

So I have to find out that $T$ is proportional to $\sqrt \ell$. How do I do that mathematically? Just guessing and seeing that it's correct is probably not the right solution, is it?

And how do I then find the constant of proportionality? Just dividing $T$ by $\sqrt\ell$?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange, Marco! I think this may actually be a more insightful question than you realize :-)

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome, David! :) And sorry for not using LaTeX! The problem is that I need an easy explanation/deduction and not something with differential equations as I've found it somewhere else. But I doubt there is an easy one ...

Comment: This is related to [Finding coefficient of proportionality](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18083/520) and the advice given in Qmechanic's answer therein is worth reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic thing to realize is that *straight lines are easy* to identify and quantify, so you want to form a ***linear relationship*** somehow or another.

---

Because you think that you know what you're going to get you can go ahead with...

$$ T = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{g}{\ell}} $$

square it to get

$$ T^2 = 4 \pi^2 \frac{g}{\ell} $$

Substitute $U = T^2$ and $s = 1/\ell$ (letters picked from thin air, BTW) to get

$$ U = 4 \pi g s $$

which is linear, So try plotting $T^2$ against $1/\ell$ and read the slope off the graph which you can equate to $4 \pi g$.

---

In the olden days{*}, of course, we would have plotted them on log-log paper if we suspected a power relationship or semi-log if we expected a exponential relationship, seen which one gave a straight line, read the slope to get the power and the intercept to get the coefficient and *then* if needed jumped through the equation manipulation hoops above to find any constant that might need to be added (and get a more accurate determination of the coefficient).

These days you could also feed the data into a math package of some kind and try fitting various functional forms until you got a good reduced Chi-squared (and don't fret if you haven't heard of that...it just means "a good fit" in carefully quantified language that a statistician would recognize).

---

{*} I got my formal training just as this style of analysis was going out of fashion--rendered unnecessary by increasingly powerful computers and analysis packages--but my Dad had taken me through the basics for my secondary school science projects. I think it is worth playing with just for the insight it provides.